# How to pass hidden field value via ajax to codeigniter controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a view file which contains a button (link):

```
<a href id="savebutton" class="btn btn-warning">Save</a>
```

Somewhere else in this view I have also declared some hidden fields in a form that contain my userid and vacancyid.

```
echo form_input(dataHiddenArray('userid', $this->auth_user_id));
echo form_input(dataHiddenArray('vacancyid', $vacancydetails[0]->vacancy_id));
```

These hidden fields translate to:

```
<input type="hidden" value="2" class="userid">
<input type="hidden" value="1" class="vacancyid">
```

Now I want to be able to send these values to my controller (via AJAX) so that I can insert them in my database.

My JS file looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    var postData = {
        "userid" : $("input.userid").val(),
        "vacancyid" : $("input.vacancyid").val()
    };                                        
        btnSave = $('#savebutton'),
        ajaxOptions = {
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/vacancy/saveVacancy",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'text'
        };

    btnSave.click(function (ev) {
        var options = $.extend({}, ajaxOptions, {
            //data : $(this).closest('form').serialize()
            data: postData
        });
        ev.preventDefault();

        // ajax done & fail
        $.ajax(options).done(function(data) {
            alert(data);        // plausible [Object object]
            //alert(data[0]);     // plausible data
            console.log(data);  // debug as an object
        }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.warn(xhr);
            console.warn(status);
            console.warn(error);
        });
    });
```

And my controller looks like this (it is not doing much because it doesn't return anything):

```
public function saveVacancy() {
        //$this->load->model('user/usersavedvacancies_model');
        /*$data = array(
            'userid' => $this->input->post('userid'),
            'vacancyid'=>$this->input->post('vacancyid')
        );*/
        echo $this->input->post('userid');
    }
```

Comment: by using `var postData = {
        "userid" : $(".userid").val(),
        "vacancyid" : $(".vacancyid").val()
    };`

Comment: what are your request parameters when it requests? I mean there should be postdata but I want to view the postdata content

Comment: @devpro alert($("input.userid").val()) does give me the correct number for the userid (2 in my case), so i think the problem should be somewhere else?

Comment: @AbhishekJain how do i view the postdata?

Comment: just use `DataType json`

Comment: @devpro changing my datatype to json makes the ajax call redirect to my 404 page

Comment: what is your `base_url()`?

Comment: i think url should be `url: "<?php echo base_url();?>vacancy/saveVacancy",` here vacancy is controller? and saveVacancy is function? right

Comment: i suppose, base_url already contains the folder name, and dashboard is your folder name right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122661/discussion-between-dennis-and-devpro).

Comment: use firebug, its a browser plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minor changes to javascript

```
$(function () {
    var postData = {
        "userid": $("input.userid").val(),
        "vacancyid": $("input.vacancyid").val()
    };
    btnSave = $('#savebutton'),
      ajaxOptions = {
          type: 'POST',
          url: "<?php echo base_url('dashboard/vacancy/saveVacancy);?>",
          dataType: 'json'
      };

    btnSave.click(function (ev) {
        var options = $.extend({}, ajaxOptions, {
            //data : $(this).closest('form').serialize()
            data: postData
        });
        ev.preventDefault();

        // ajax done & fail
        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);  // debug as an object
            if (data.result === 'success') {
                alert("Yeah, it saved userid " + data.userid + " to vacancy id " + data.vacancyid);
            }
        }).fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.warn(xhr);
            console.warn(status);
            console.warn(error);
        });
    });
});
```

In the controller

```
public function saveVacancy()
{
    //assigning a more useable object name to the model during load
    $this->load->model('user/usersavedvacancies_model', 'save_vacancy'); 

    $data = array(
        'userid' => $this->input->post('userid'),
        'vacancyid' => $this->input->post('vacancyid')
    );
    //send data to model and model returns true or false for success or failure
    $saved = $this->save_vacancy->doSaveId($data); //yes, I made up the method, change it
    $result = $saved ? "success" : "failed";
    echo json_encode(array('result' => $result, 'userid' => $data['userid'], 'vacancyid' => $data['vacancyid']));
}
```

Comment: This worked!! Thank you SO much! Can you tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Mostly a case of matching the type of data returned to that which jquery was expecting. Also, your use of the ajax option `contentType` wasn't helping.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that $.ajax takes two methods i.e GET and POST and from the documentation you can see that default method is GET so Since you have not defined method as GET/POST probably the method is taken GET so first change define ajax method to POST as well as you need to be clear about dataType of ajax it may be one of JSON/html and default is json.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  dataType:'html'

});
```

I guess this helped you can learn detail from 
[Learn more](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).